# Importing Microsoft Access in to a Ruby on Rails MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, ruby, ms-access

I need to import data from a Microsoft Access database through Ruby in to a MySQL database programmaticly. I need the process to be as easy as possible, as the goals is for a non technical user to obtain the access database, upload it to the Rails application, and ingest the data in to the new database.

Is there a way to do this on a Mac or Linux environment completely through Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

1) export the access file as a CSV

2) you can use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

example:

```
   mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.csv'
       -> INTO TABLE mytable
       -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY ''
       -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```